# access_token - Script to upload photo in fan page album

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page, facebook-access-token

I am developing an app to include in my page tab. In this app, the user will go take a picture with your webcam and the picture will sent to an especific album in my fan page.

I found an script here: and he is working very well, but I've a problem, the script use an user access_token to upload the picture, dont's necessary ask permission of all users to upload the picture because the script use my administrator user to send to the page.

The big problem is: The user access token expire after 2 hours or when my admin user not logged in, the permission offline_access was discontinued and I don't know how my script will work.

I need that all user can upload photo using the system, anyone know how I can work?

Here is the script in PHP:

```
`
require_once 'library/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '<appid>',
    'secret' => '<appsecret>',
    'fileUpload' => true
));
$access_token = 'access_token';
$params = array('access_token' => $access_token);
$fanpage = 'page_id';
$album_id ='album_id';
$accounts = $facebook->api('/ADMIN_ACCOUNT/accounts', 'GET', $params);

foreach($accounts['data'] as $account) {
    if( $account['id'] == $fanpage || $account['name'] == $fanpage ){
        $fanpage_token = $account['access_token'];
    }
}

$valid_files = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
$img = realpath("image_path");

$args = array(
    'message' => 'message to write in legend',
    'image' => '@' . $img,
    'aid' => $album_id,
    'no_story' => 1,
    'access_token' => $fanpage_token
);

$photo = $facebook->api($album_id . '/photos', 'post', $args);

if( is_array( $photo ) && !empty( $photo['id'] ) ){
    echo '<p><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid='.$photo['id'].'">Click here to watch this photo on Facebook.</a></p>';
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to request a long-lived access token by hitting the endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Take a look at Scenario 4 on the following document:
http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Tks, the access token is valid to two months now.

And in this way is possible to make an script to renew automaticaly the access token? Using a curl to get the new access token before to this expire. Can this work?

Comment: no, the user needs to come back every so often for you to get an extended token

Comment: @Igy Thinking better really, the token is generated only if my user has logged on fb, so, it's impossible to create an script to renew the token automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using that script to post to a fan page’s album, then you should get a *page* access token – they don’t expire.

Details see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

Comment: Tks @CBroe but, the script works as an user script to upload in the page, this script will  be used in a short time for an especific promotion and use an token with long expire will go work fine.