# Facebook Graph API session expiration

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I use the following PHP code to publish random messages from my database to my Facebook fan page:

```
require_once('src/facebook.php');
$appid = 'MY_APP_ID';
$appsecret = 'APP_SECRET';
$pageid = 'MY_PAGE_ID';
$token = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $appid,
  'secret' => $appsecret,
));

$message = 'Hello World';

//Information that makes up the facebook page post
$attachment = array(
        'access_token' => $token,
        'message' => $message
);

//Try to post to the facebook page
try{
$res = $facebook->api('/'.$pageid.'/feed','POST',$attachment);

} catch (Exception $e){

    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

And here is `src/facebook.php` - https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php

But it return the error message something like this:

```
Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1339020000. The current unix time is 1339022625.
```

So my question is what  changes should I do in my code ?

P.S: I also looked relevant questions about session expiration, but none of them helped me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: facebook already depreciated access token .check this out https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: @RaquibulIslam, Facebook **DID NOT** deprecated `access_token` but `offline_access` permission (which was used to get "permanent" `access_token`)

Comment: @JuicyScripter ya you are right , i miss typed that :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using your user access token and not a page access token in this case.

You should be authenticating against the application with the `manage_pages` permission which will give you access to retrieve access tokens for your page. These have a longer expiration period.

After authorizing this permission and retrieving a valid access token for the current user, you should make a request to the following endpoint to retrieve a list of pages and applications you manage:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

In this response is included an access token for these pages and applications:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "PAGE_TITLE", 
      "access_token": "PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN", 
      "category": "PAGE_CATEGORY", 
      "id": "PAGE_ID"
    },
```

You can see more information about this here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

**Updated**

For expired access token you will need to reauthenticate your user by accessing your app via a browser and following the authentication flow.

The documentation on how to handle this is here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/

You can then request a longer lived access token these do still expire. You can see information about how to request one of these here under scenario 4:
http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I'm sure that use page's access token. Since the session going to be expired, the problem is I have to get new access token before I post message to page. But I don't know how to get :(

Comment: if it's expired, you will have to reauthenticate as the user and retrieve a new access token.

Comment: So my question is how can I reauthenticate as the user and retrieve a new access token in my code. Because every session (access token) life is 2 hours

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918954/access-token-script-to-upload-photo-in-fan-page-album/